# What if UV behaviour of gravity was perturbative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity, perturbation-theory

I understand that the UV behaviour of gravity ought to be dominated by black hole production and that graviton-graviton scattering ought to blow up above the Planck scale. Suppose, however, that gravity was somehow screened above the Planck scale, so that gravity was of constant strength, rather than ever increasing strength, above the Planck scale, and somehow remained perturbative.

Would this imply a maximum curvature? and therefore a minimum radius/mass for a black hole, since small black holes require more curvature. Also, I guess there could be no singularity within a black hole. Could black holes still form, given that arbitrarily small black holes can't exist in this model?

Assuming Hawking radiation, a massive black hole would decay until it reached that minimum radius, at which point it would cease to be a black hole. The contents, and information, would be no longer be trapped, and there was no singularity for it to hit. It would just come out, I suppose.

Is this scenario at all plausible? Where is there likely to be trouble? Does this violate any experiments? Theoretical principles?

Comment: As a side remark, some people argue that this happens in the IR for QCD: QCD would be perturbative in the UV, and attracted to another perturbative fixed point in the IR.

For gravity, it seems that the UV fixed point people find is not trivial, so your scenario does not work in this asymptotic safety scenario.